# Table block - Wrap table

Tags: block-editor, table

I am using Gutenberg to create tables. Gutenberg tables have the following front-end structure :

```
<figure class="wp-block-table">
   <table>
      ...
   </table>
</figure>
```

I'd like to add a drop-shadow to my table but it doesn't work due to `overflow-x : auto` on the parent element `figure`.

One fix would be to wrap the table like this :

```
<figure class="wp-block-table">
   <div class="table-wrapper">
      <table>
         ...
      </table>
   </div>
</figure>
```

Is there a way to easily wrap the `table` ? I've seen a way to wrap a whole gutenberg block (using `render_block` filter) but no only a child element.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the `<table>` strings and replace them with the wrapper element:

```php
function pb_table_render_block($block_content, $block) {
    if ($block['blockName'] == 'core/table') {
        $block_content = str_replace('<table', '<div class="table-wrapper"><table', $block_content);
        $block_content = str_replace('</table>', '</table></div>', $block_content);
    }

    return $block_content;
}
add_filter('render_block', 'pb_table_render_block', 10, 2);
```